# Can you apply Ruffini's method to root-finding of non-polynomial functions?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, roots

Ruffini's rule is a technique for dividing a polynomial by a binomial of the form x − r. I wonder whether it makes sense to apply the same technique for numerically find roots of non-polynomial functions.  Any ideas? Maybe there exists work along that direction?

Comment: Reference to "Ruffini's rule"?

Comment: If you read the relevant Horner and Ruffini papers, then you will find that they are concerned with root-finding for functions where the Taylor expansion is available. The division of linear factors is a minor step in that and attributed to Newton/Lagrange.